# Installing RVM/Ruby 1.9.3 via Chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, ruby-1.9.3

I'm just getting started with trying to move my infrastructure over to Chef, and I think I must be missing something obvious.

I'm using the [chef-rvm](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm) cookbook to install RVM, and I'd like it to install Ruby 1.9.3p125 and set that as the default.

Here's my base server role:

```
name "base"
description "Basic configuration for all nodes"
run_list(
  'recipe[git]',
  'recipe[sudo]',
  'recipe[ubuntu]',
  'recipe[rvm]',
  'recipe[postgresql::client]'
)

override_attributes(
  :authorization => {
    :sudo => {
      :users => ["ubuntu"],
      :passwordless => true
    }
  },
  :rvm => {
    :rubies => ["ruby-1.9.3-p125"],
    :default_ruby => "ruby-1.9.3-p125",
    :global_gems => ['bundler', 'rake']
  }
)
```

This runs without any problems, but if I ssh into the server after it's finished, rvm doesn't list any installed rubies:

```
ubuntu@test.server:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies


# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

Is this even the correct way to specify that certain rubies be installed? If not, what is the correct way? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The problem lies in the fact that you never told Chef to install the Rubies that you defined in your role.

You have included `recipe[rvm]` in the role's `run_list`, which translates to `recipe[rvm::default]`. Looking into the cookbook's documentation, you find that this recipe:

*Installs the RVM gem and initializes Chef to use the Lightweight Resources and Providers (LWRPs).* **Use this recipe explicitly if you only want access to the LWRPs provided.**

What you want can be best achieved by substituting `recipe[rvm]` for `recipe[rvm::system]` in the `run_list`:

*Installs the RVM codebase system-wide (that is, into /usr/local/rvm) and installs Rubies, global gems, and specific gems driven off attribute metadata. This recipe includes default and system* _ *install.*
**Use this recipe by itself if you want RVM system-wide with Rubies installed, etc.**