# How to install rvm/ruby/rails via chef?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, vagrant

First, I would like to point out that I have read the question located here: [Installing RVM/Ruby 1.9.3 via Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242695/installing-rvm-ruby-1-9-3-via-chef)

I am trying to set up a Ruby on Rails environment in Windows using VirtualBox/Vagrant.  The installation of VirtualBox and Vagrant are pretty self-explanatory, but delving into the configuration of Vagrant and things like Chef become less clear.

I am following instructions from a blog here: http://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2013/07/23/developing-ruby-on-rails-on-windows/

Which include installation of the librarian-chef gem to manage cookbooks, and using the following Cheffile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#^syntax detection

site 'http://community.opscode.com/api/v1'

cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'git'
cookbook 'sqlite'
cookbook 'mysql'
cookbook 'postgresql'
cookbook 'database', :git => 'git://github.com/manuelvanrijn/cookbook-database.git', :ref => 'grant-roles'
cookbook 'nodejs'
cookbook 'build-essential'
cookbook 'ruby_build'
cookbook 'rbenv', :git => 'git://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv.git', :ref => 'v0.7.2'
```

My problem is that launching my Vagrant box initially, and the base box (precise64) that I am using comes with ruby 1.8.7p358.

In order to get a functioning Rails site, I needed to install rvm, install a newer version of Ruby, then install Rails before I was able to run `rails new rails_site`

I have found a cookbook for rvm here: https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm

So what I am hoping to accomplish is, add the rvm cookbook, automatically install a specific version of Ruby, and then install Rails, so that I can have a functional development environment out of the box.  I know that I can add the cookbook by adding a line at the end of my Cheffile, but beyond that, how do I also instruct rvm to install a specific version of Ruby, then after that, to install Rails as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install rvm, I have used cookbook [you specified](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm). What you need is to add it to Cheffile:

```
cookbook 'rvm', :git => 'git://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm.git', :ref => '24ecbb0'
```

I have used ref, because last version wasn't working properly(don't know if it was fixed, but you can try my way, then switch and tryout newer). Next step is to add rvm to the role you are using for your node:

```
'recipe[rvm::user]',
```

after you specified this role in nodefile(in your tutorial it is Vagrantfile), you can configure rvm installation like this:

```
  'rvm' => {
    'installer_url' => 'https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer',
    'branch' => 'none',
    'version' => '1.17.10',
    'user_installs' => [{        
      'user' => 'someuser',
      'default_ruby' => 'ruby-1.9.3-p286@mygemsetname'
    }]
  }
```

thats it. Rvm should be installed for `someuser` with `ruby-1.9.3-p286@mygemsetname` gemset. To install Rails in specific dir and other custom actions you will need to learn how to write own cookbooks, it is very easy, you will need to log-in as `someuser`, cd to dir you need and execute `gem install`, then `rails new`(of course if you want to install rvm/rails as a user, not systemwide)

**UPD:**
To install custom gems you can use [chef-rvm](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm#-gems) or your own cookbook:

`./site_cookbooks/mycookbook/recipes/default.rb`

```
execute 'install mysql2 gem' do
  command 'gem install mysql2'
  not_if 'gem list | grep mysql2'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  If I wanted to install rvm system wide, then I would use `recipe[rvm::system]` in the role, right?  Also, is there a way to include the `gem install` part in Chef somehow, so that all that would be required after booting the box and ssh in, would be to `rails new` and be on your way developing?

Comment: Also, the virtual machine is running Ubuntu precise, as you mention in your post.  My host environment is Windows, which is why I am practically forced to go the virtual machine route to get a good development environment for Ruby on Rails.

Comment: You are right, you need `rvm::system`. I don't know other ways to install gems except own cookbook creation. If you will create it, all you need is to add new line to role-file `'recipe[mycookbook]',` and it will be installed during provision

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I am new to Vagrant and Chef, so this is quite the learning experience!

Comment: I added the `rvm::system` recipe in my role, it shows that it ran it in the provisioning, but when I login and type `rvm -v` the machine says rvm is not installed.  Any ideas?

Comment: you should check installation path from recipe(it could be something like `/usr/local/rvm/bin`) and maybe add executable to $PATH(bin/sbin folders if it isn't there)

Comment: `default['rvm']['root_path']     = "/usr/local/rvm"`

it should be here

Comment: I found `default['rvm']['root_path'] = "/usr/local/rvm"` in the file `rvm/attributes/default.rb`, is that where it should be?  I also had tried the `rbenv` cookbook, but it had the same issue, where it just didn't seem to be installing.  Is there a step I could be missing after the provisioning?

Comment: yes, you should check if it is being installed into `/usr/local/rvm` and I found that you can actually install gems using chef-rvm, I have updated an answer

Comment: `/usr/local/rvm` directory does not exist.  It appears that my cookbooks aren't actually installing anything.  I just manually installed everything for now to get my development environment, but I am really hoping to figure out how to get Vagrant set up correctly with Chef so that I can recreate the same environment on multiple machines.  Do you have any recommendations for information that would help?